# Wordpress Woocommerce Sorting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to sort the products in our website via most sales (popularity) but I also want to push a few specific and newer products to the top because otherwise it takes ages for users to find them.

There are the two following options

- custom/default order
- popularity

The issue is that with the custom/default option, it sorts all products that don't have a set priority by the alphabet and not by sales.

Is there a way to use the default sorting but use the popularity sorting unless a priority is set?